# How to create "blocks" with Regex

Tags: regex, expression, block

For a project of mine, I want to create 'blocks' with Regex.

```
\xyz\yzx //wrong format
x\12 //wrong format
12\x //wrong format
\x12\x13\x14\x00\xff\xff //correct format
```

When using Regex101 to test my regular expressions, I came to [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZUIoqF/2) result:

```
([\\x(0-9A-Fa-f)])/gm
```

This leads to an incorrect output, because

```
12\x
```

Still gets detected as a correct string, though the order is wrong, it needs to be in the order specified below, and in no other order.

```
backslash x 0-9A-Fa-f 0-9A-Fa-f
```

Can anyone explain how that works and why it works in that way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you need to validate a string that consists of those blocks only? Like [`^(?:\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZUIoqF/3)? Or do you need to match those blocks in a longer string ([`\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/8pFM79/1))?

Comment: Edit: Your second Regex works, could you explain to me why it does check the whole string, instead of it stopping after the first 'finding', like the first regex you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the `\`, folloed with `x`, followed with 2 hex chars,  anywhere in the string, you need to use

```
\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8pFM79/1)

To force it match all non-overlapping occurrences, use the specific modifiers (like `/g` in JavaScript/Perl) or specific functions in your programming language (`Regex.Matches` in .NET, or `preg_match_all` in PHP, etc.).

The [`^(?:\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZUIoqF/3) regex validates a whole string that consists of the patterns like above. It happens due to the `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors. Note the `(?:...)+` is a non-capturing group that can repeat in the string 1 or more times (due to `+` quantifier).

Some [Java demo](http://ideone.com/zlMKPP):

```
String s = "\\x12\\x13\\x14\\x00\\xff\\xff";

// Extract valid blocks
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    res.add(matcher.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(res); // => [\x12, \x13, \x14, \x00, \xff, \xff]

// Check if a string consists of valid "blocks" only
boolean isValid = s.matches("(?i)(?:\\\\x[a-f0-9]{2})+");
System.out.println(isValid);  // => true
```

Note that we may shorten `[a-zA-Z]` to `[a-z]` if we add a case insensitive modifier `(?i)` to the start of the pattern, or just use `\p{Alnum}` that matches any alphanumeric char in a Java regex.

The `String#matches` method always anchors the regex by default, we do not need the leading `^` and trailing `$` anchors when using the pattern inside it.

Comment: If I use this on the website, it works. Whenever I put it in Java, it does not function anymore. I use the matches("\\\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}") function of a String in Java, but it always tells me my output is wrong.

Edit: pressed enter too early

Comment: **What is the input string and what is the expected output?** `String#matches` method requires the whole string to match the pattern, as if it were enclosed with `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: Also, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/zlMKPP) for a way to *extract* all "valid" occurrences of your "blocks".

Comment: The input is "\\x10\\x11\\x12\\x13\\x14\\x15\\x16\\x17", which should result in a 'true' as output. If the input is 'wrong', e.g. "\\x10\\x11\\x12\\x13\\x14\\x15\\16\\x17" (the 'x' is missing at \x16), I expect the output to be false.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with your code! Thank you for the time!